# JSON to string in iOS5

Tags: ios, string, json, ios5, nsjsonserialization

I found a code snippet [here](http://www.lifeofatechdude.com/2012/01/nsjsonserialization-convert-nsstring-to.html), which I wanted to use, but I can't figure out how to make it back "to string" and see if it works...

```
// some strings for test
NSString *cpu = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [_cpuSlider value]];
NSString *ram = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [_ramSlider value]];
NSString *hdd = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [_hddSlider value]];

// put them into dictionary
NSDictionary *test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:cpu, @"CPU", ram, @"RAM", hdd, @"HDD", nil];
// start of the code from page above
NSMutableData *myData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];  
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:myData];  
[archiver encodeObject:test forKey:@"MyKEY"];  
[archiver finishEncoding];  
id testJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:0 error:nil];
// end of code

// HERE I'd like know what to put in to see it as a string..e.g. { "CPU"=value; etc...}
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MLIA" message:????? delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Zavřít" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[av show];
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSKeyedArchiver` doesn't produce JSON (AFAIK), so I don't know how that linked example could possibly work. If you want to JSON-encode a dictionary, you would use `+dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`:

```
NSError *err;
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:test options:0 error:&err];
NSAssert1(json, @"Error: %@", err);

// If not using ARC, remember to (auto)release repr.
NSString *repr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[UIAlertView …] … message:repr …];
```

Comment: That's so geniously simple! Thanks a lot! What do you mean "don't forget to autorelease"? I am quite new to iOS development, but isn't that deprecated thanks to ARC?

Comment: If you use ARC, then yes, you can (must!) skip the release. Not everyone uses ARC yet, due to legacy code and libraries.

Comment: @MarceloCantos you might want to point out what exactly it is that needs to be released here. In this case it's the the string 'repr' because it was created with an alloc-init. The json object should be an autoreleased object according to my understanding.